# When i put a variable on javascript style method, Why css is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
let second = document.querySelector('.second');
let secondNed = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    secondNed += 6;
    if (secondNed == 360) {
        secondNed = 0;
    }
    second.style.transform = `rotate(${secondNed}deg);`
    console.log(secondNed);
}, 1000);
```

So my question is how can I put variable inside style?

( In this specific case - how can I set  CSS transform property using the secondNed variable )

Comment: As side note, this line `secondNed ´+= 6; if (secondNed == 360) { secondNed = 0; }` can be shortend to: `secondNed = (secondNed + 6) % 360`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the value of the CSS property.

```js
second.style.transform = `rotate(${secondNed}deg)`; 
// note semicolon is outside the string
```

Alternatively, you could set the CSS [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate) property instead.

```js
second.style.rotate = secondNed + 'deg';
```